# strtok() being called within a while loop, but the results are showing duplicates

Tags: c, strtok

I'm currently creating a simple shell program that takes in input commands and executes them. I'm on the part where I need to parse through the inputted commands using strtok() but I'm getting duplicates of the first command in my char[].

```
int parse_command(char command[], char *args[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (args[i] != NULL) {
        args[i] = strtok(command, " \n");
        //cout << args[i];
        i++;    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In my main, I'm just running:

```
execvp(args[0], args);
```

Comment: Have a better look at the strtok() man page - at some stage you should be passing NULL as the first argument.

Comment: That's not how you use `strtok`. There must be loads of examples you can copy from. In any case `strtok` is a dangerous function because if relies on hidden global state. I would advise against using it at all.

Comment: The other disadvantage of `strtok()` in any form (`strtok_r()`, `strtok_s()`, `strsep()`) is that they zap the delimiter character with a null byte, so you can't tell which delimiter was found unless you're working on a copy of the original string.  This doesn't matter too much while you're looking for white space (blanks and newlines shown; you would probably want to add tabs too, in due course), but when you start dealing with other constructs (I/O redirection for example), it matters.  NB: `echo Abracadabra>&2` writes to standard error, no space between the `a` and the `>&2`.

Answer (score 2):

Correct use of `strtok()`:

```
for( char *cp = command; (cp = strtok( cp, " \n" ) ) != NULL; cp = NULL ) {
    puts( cp );
    /* store these away if that's what you intend */
}
```

Comment: Not my down vote as the code seems to be correct, but very ugly.

Comment: @john The usual paradigm has two invocations of the function, usually each with their own reiterations (duplications) of the delimiter string... For the simple case, this is "tight", not "ugly"... Opinions are opinions `:-)` It is, after all, a _function_... You put something in and get out a result. `:-)`

Comment: I agree that this code is ugly, however I also agree that code duplication is ugly. What I especially like about this answer is that the delimiter string is not duplicated, as it would be in most other solutions. Therefore, I am upvoting this answer.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thank you. `:-)`... Another positive of this example is that the scope of `cp` is restricted to just this `for()` loop... That _other_ way (using `while()`) requires a viable variable outside of the loop. Cheers! `:-)`

Comment: Clever. I like it.

Comment: Thank you @Fe2O3. This solution wasn't working on my mac's terminal but using a different IDE, like Replit, solved my issue. This solution still gives me duplicates of my first inputted command on my mac's terminal, so I think its just an issue somewhere else in my code or somewhere on my actual machine.